# How to calculate the 99th percentile of a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset of the mean of weights of two sample sizes, I have 100,000 tests and I am trying to find out the 99th percentile but I do not understand how to do so, I have found out the median quartile by doing the following;

```
summary(Lifts)
 Large           Small      
 Min.   : 62.5   Min.   : 54.2  
 1st Qu.: 99.1   1st Qu.: 96.0  
 Median :106.0   Median :106.0  
 Mean   :106.0   Mean   :106.0  
 3rd Qu.:112.9   3rd Qu.:116.0  
 Max.   :147.5   Max.   :156.8
```

I need to find the 99th percentile of both the large and the small, I have tried using the quartile command;

```
quantile(Lifts, probs = c(0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.99))
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

But I receive that error

any help would be appreciated

Comment: `quantile` expects a vector, but you've given it a data frame. Why not make a vector of the two columns and use that? I'm assuming that when you say you want the percentile of both columns, you mean all values between the two columns, not individually...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we specify the column (for example using `$` notation) we get rid of the error:

```
quantile(Lifts$Large, probs = c(0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.99))
```

Or

```
quantile(Lifts$Small, probs = c(0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.99))
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, to apply a function on all columns of a data frame, we can use `lapply`, which also works with `quantile`.

```
lapply(lifts, quantile, probs=c(0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.99))
# $large
#       0%     25%     50%     99% 
#   14.400 161.675 488.450 950.506 
# 
# $small
#      0%    25%    50%    99% 
#   0.900 30.800 43.650 97.744
```

We also may use `sapply` which does the same but yields as output a matrix.

```
sapply(lifts, quantile, probs=c(0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.99))
#       large  small
# 0%   14.400  0.900
# 25% 161.675 30.800
# 50% 488.450 43.650
# 99% 950.506 97.744
```

---

*Data*

```
lifts <- structure(list(large = c(489.9, 734.5, 905.6, 41.9, 950.2, 73.9, 
444.7, 950.8, 303.9, 539, 399.4, 429.5, 670.2, 39.1, 324.6, 829.6, 
97.9, 216.6, 500.1, 364.4, 762.6, 205.7, 191.6, 128.6, 749.2, 
185, 736.9, 46.9, 114.2, 774.4, 626.5, 42.5, 52.5, 724.3, 518.3, 
932.7, 602.5, 14.4, 794.9, 149.7, 621.6, 674.2, 685.1, 153.9, 
42.3, 487, 787.5, 351.6, 689.3, 862.3), small = c(56.5, 63.6, 
49.5, 76.7, 78, 25.8, 57.8, 19.2, 27.7, 38.3, 36.4, 4.4, 89.2, 
68.8, 36.1, 71.8, 69.1, 35.8, 38.2, 26.9, 95.5, 30.7, 43.2, 58.8, 
44.1, 35.4, 91.2, 37.1, 99.9, 94.5, 52, 38.2, 40.1, 50.9, 81.7, 
7.5, 77.5, 71.9, 70.6, 8.2, 90.1, 31.1, 3.4, 52, 0.9, 30.5, 12.7, 
45.6, 34.2, 13.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L
))
```